# pressing enter just appends values to url and doesnt completely replace url with searchForm String

Tags: javascript, html

hi i am having a problem where pressing enter appends values while the input field is focused. what i want to do is press enter and then it brings me to google bing etc.
So before searching my url is
http://127.0.0.1:5500/Newtab%20Home/index.html
then pressing enter while searching "what is today" it changes the url to
http://127.0.0.1:5500/Newtab%20Home/index.html?searchText=what+is+today&whichEngine=Google
when i want it to search on google not 127.0.0.1

my javascript code is:

```
        document.getElementById("searchBtn").addEventListener("click", startSearch);
            
            function startSearch(){
            searchString = document.searchForm.searchText.value; 
            if(searchString != ""){
            searchEngine = document.searchForm.whichEngine.selectedIndex + 1;
            
            if(searchEngine == 1){
            finalSearchString = "https://www.google.com/search?&q=" + searchString;
            }
            if(searchEngine == 2){
            finalSearchString = "https://yandex.com/search/?text=" + searchString;
            }
            if(searchEngine == 3){
            finalSearchString = "https://searx.fmac.xyz/search?q=" + searchString;
            }
            if(searchEngine == 4){
            finalSearchString = "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" + searchString;
            }
            if(searchEngine == 5){
            finalSearchString = "https://www.startpage.com/do/search?query=" + searchString;
            }
            if(searchEngine == 6){
            finalSearchString = "https://filepursuit.com/pursuit?q=" + searchString + "&type=all";
            }
            if(searchEngine == 7){
            finalSearchString = "https://www.filechef.com/?fileType=&query=" + searchString + "&eventAction=All+Files#";
            }
            if(searchEngine == 8){
            finalSearchString = "http://www.aiosearch.com/search/4/Torrents/" + searchString;
            }
            
       
            location.href = finalSearchString;

            }

          var input = document.getElementById("searchText");

          // Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard
          input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
          // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
          if (event.keyCode === 13) {
          // Cancel the default action, if needed
          event.preventDefault();
          // Trigger the button element with a click
          document.getElementById("searchBtn").click();
          }
          });

          }
```

HTML:

```
<form name="searchForm" class="d-flex justify-content-center" id="searchEngine">
            
            <table width=1000 border cellpadding=3 cellspacing=2 bgcolor=444444>
            
            <tr>
            <td><font size=3 face="Verdana, Arial, sans-serif">Input Search Term:<br>
            <td><font size=3 face="Verdana, Arial, sans-serif">Site:
            <td>&nbsp;
            
            <tr>
            <td><input name="searchText" type="text" id="sInput">
            <td>
            <select name="whichEngine">
            <option selected>Google
            <option>Yandex
            <option>Searx
            <option>DuckDuckGo
            <option>StartPage
            <option>FilePursuit
            <option>FileChef
            <option>AioSearch
            </select>
            <td><input type="button" id="searchBtn" value="Send">
            
            </select>
            </table>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was caused by your confusion, I believe, something very simple. In  when you click on keyCode 13 (Enter), it calls the Submit event of the form, to resolve this you can get the  and get the submit event using the preventDefault on it. Another problem was in the input you took, first that it is inside the startSearch function does not make much sense, then you were taking an id that does not exist, the correct id name was "sInput".

#### Code

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener('submit', e => e.preventDefault())
        document.getElementById("searchBtn").addEventListener("click", startSearch);

        var input = document.getElementById("sInput");
        // Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard
        input.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
            // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                // Cancel the default action, if needed
                event.preventDefault();
                // Trigger the button element with a click
                document.getElementById("searchBtn").click();
            }
        });
        function startSearch(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            searchString = document.searchForm.searchText.value;
            if (searchString != "") {
                searchEngine = document.searchForm.whichEngine.selectedIndex + 1;

                if (searchEngine == 1) {
                    finalSearchString = "https://www.google.com/search?&q=" + searchString;
                }
                if (searchEngine == 2) {
                    finalSearchString = "https://yandex.com/search/?text=" + searchString;
                }
                if (searchEngine == 3) {
                    finalSearchString = "https://searx.fmac.xyz/search?q=" + searchString;
                }
                if (searchEngine == 4) {
                    finalSearchString = "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" + searchString;
                }
                if (searchEngine == 5) {
                    finalSearchString = "https://www.startpage.com/do/search?query=" + searchString;
                }
                if (searchEngine == 6) {
                    finalSearchString = "https://filepursuit.com/pursuit?q=" + searchString + "&type=all";
                }
                if (searchEngine == 7) {
                    finalSearchString = "https://www.filechef.com/?fileType=&query=" + searchString + "&eventAction=All+Files#";
                }
                if (searchEngine == 8) {
                    finalSearchString = "http://www.aiosearch.com/search/4/Torrents/" + searchString;
                }

                location.href = finalSearchString;

            }

        }
```

```html
<form name="searchForm" class="d-flex justify-content-center" id="searchEngine">

        <table width=1000 border cellpadding=3 cellspacing=2 bgcolor=444444>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <font size=3 face="Verdana, Arial, sans-serif">Input Search Term:<br>
                <td>
                    <font size=3 face="Verdana, Arial, sans-serif">Site:
                <td>&nbsp;

            <tr>
                <td><input name="searchText" type="text" id="sInput">
                <td>
                    <select name="whichEngine">
                        <option selected>Google
                        <option>Yandex
                        <option>Searx
                        <option>DuckDuckGo
                        <option>StartPage
                        <option>FilePursuit
                        <option>FileChef
                        <option>AioSearch
                    </select>
                <td><input type="button" id="searchBtn" value="Send">

                    </select>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: In the stack overflow you will not be able to see the results correctly, as it refuses to connect to google, but you can copy and test it on your machine.